# Square ABCD of side a and N on AB. Find radius of congruent incircles of ACN and BCN

Tags: euclidean-geometry, triangles

ABCD is a square with side a and diagonal AC. The incircles, with radius r, of the triangles ACN and BCN are congruent, with N in AB. What is the radius r in terms of a?

Comment: I just want a hint...

Comment: If the question is of `high level maths` and you only post the question without any attempt of resolution or previus research, you will get a lot of answers and upvotes. But if your question is of `low level maths` you will get a lot of downvotes and close votes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Let $BN = x$. Then, $AN = a-x$ and $CN = \sqrt{x^2+a^2}$. Establish the triangle areas below

$$Area_{NBC} =\frac12 NB \cdot BC = \frac12r\cdot (NB+BC + NC)$$
$$Area_{NAC} =\frac12 NA \cdot BC = \frac12r\cdot (NA+AC + NC)$$

or

$$xa= r(x+a+\sqrt{x^2+a^2})$$
$$(x-a)a= r(a-x+\sqrt2 a+\sqrt{x^2+a^2})$$

Solve to obtain $x=\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt2-1}2}a$ and the radius

$$r = \frac12(1-\sqrt{\sqrt2-1})a$$

Comment: Thanks, @Quanto! Great solution!

Comment: @Cavalo - you’re welcome